# Bitwise operator on two large sparse vectors without looping?

Tags: c++, std

I have three large arbitrary sparse boolean vectors, all of the same size - say: `pool1`, `pool2`, `intersection_of_other_pools`. I'm interested in performing a bitwise operator. It'd be great if I could do: `intersection_of_other_pools |= pool1 | pool2`, but that doesn't seem to be an option - as far as I could find.

Since the size of all these vectors are very large, and `pool1` and `pool2` are very sparse, I'd be interested in a way to perform a bitwise operation on these vectors *without* looping. I understand that the under-the-hood implementation of `std::vector<bool>` is just an array of bits, which led me to believe it's possible to do this without looping.

I'm open to strange bitwise hacky solutions in the name of speed.

Of course, if the fastest way (or the only way) to do this is just looping, then I'll happily accept that as an answer as well.

I've checked out [valarray](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libstdc++-v3/include/std/valarray.html#1140) as a potential alternative to vector, but I couldn't tell if it looping or is doing some magical bitwise operation. But ideally, I don't want to change the existing codebase.

Comment: I think that in any case you can not do the operation without some kind of loop.

Comment: Say you have more than 512 bits in a vector and latest MMX only supports 256 bit operations, hypothetically. How would the compiler, in your mind, would go about implementing the operation?

Comment: Is iterating through 256 bit chunks faster then iterating through each individual item? If so, I suppose I'd iterate through the chunks and perform the bitwise operation on the chunks.

Comment: What's wrong with looping? This isn't Python. There is no magical non-loop operation that applies to gigabytes of memory all at once.

Be aware: under the hood, `std::vector<bool>` is an array of *bytes*. Computers don't have individual bits.

What problem are you actually trying to solve, because there's no reason to be scared of loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `std::vector<bool>` or similar for a sparse array.

A truly sparse array should have the ability to skip over large sections.

Encode your data as block headers, which state how long a region it is in bytes.  Use all 1s in the length to say "the length of the length field is twice as long and follows", recursively.

So 0xFF0100 states that there is a block of length 512 following.  (you can do a bit better by not permitting 0 nor 1-254, but that is rounding error).

Alternate blocks of "all 0s" with blocks of mixed 1s and 0s.

Don't read the block headers directly; use memcpy into aligned storage.

Once you have this, your `|` or `&` operation is more of a stitch than a bitwise operation.  Only in the rare case where both have a non-zero block do you actually do bitwise work.

After doing `&` you might want to check if any of the non-0 regions are actually all 0.

This assumes an *extremely sparse bitfield*.  Like, 1 bit in every few 10000 is set is a typical case.  If by sparse you mean "1 in 10", then just use a vector of `uint64_t` or something.

Answer (score 2):

implement as `std::vector<uint64_t>`, your cpu will propably be quite fast to do the bitwise "or" on these. They will be memory-aligned, so cache friendly.
the loop is not as bad as you think, as there will be a hidden implicit loop anyway on a different data structure.

if its extremly sparse (<< 1 in 1000), then just store the indices of the "set" bits in a (sorted) vector and use [std::set_intersection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) to do the matching